# Accessing application on websphere through iPlanet web server

Tags: web, webserver, websphere, iplanet

I have an application that is running when directed hit using websphere application server(using the default port of the app server). What I want is that the application should be accessed using the iPlanet web server available.

I need to know the changes to be made to config files of the web server or app server concerned. Also do I need to make changes in obj.conf config file of iPlanet Web Server.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at
[WAS Software Requirements page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/prodguid/v1r0/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=1345529544358&osPlatform=Solaris#)
it refers to Sun Java System Web Server and I'm not sure that it match iPlanet product.

If it is supported you could administer it as other web server see: [Administering web servers from the administrative console](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/container_webservers_console_administering.html)

Otherwise, it could be quite quite difficult to use iPlanet as HTTP Server.
In fact, you can configure iPlanet to behave as a [Reverse Proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19146-01/821-1828/6nmpm01bn/) to route some HTTP requests (e.g. /yourapp/*) to WAS but you need to add a configuration for each app.

Moreover, if you have a WAS cluster, you will lose session affinity that is a capability of HTTP plugin provided by WAS: [Configuring simple load balancing across multiple application server profiles](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twsv_configsimplelb.html).

I suggest you to use Web Server supported by WAS like IBM HTTP Server (the license is included in WAS)